# Background task - how to stop in a controlled manner?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a WPF application that will have an "indexing service" running as a background task. The indexing service will utilise a FileSystemWatcher that monitors a folder - when a file changes the indexing service will read in the file contents and update an index (I'm using Lucene.Net). My indexing service is a singleton, and will be started during application startup like this:-

```
new TaskFactory().StartNew(_indexingService.StartService);
```

The `StartService()` method looks something like this:-

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void StartService()
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        // Set the properties
    };
    watcher.Changed += UpdateIndexes();

    _resetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

When the application is closing, I intend to call this method, which I understand will end the indexing service background task:-

```
public void StopService()
{
    _resetEvent.Set();
}
```

First of all, is this the right "pattern" for starting and stopping a background task that should run for the lifetime of an application?

Second, how "graceful" would this shutdown be? Let's say that the watcher `Changed` event handler has fired and is iterating through the files, reading them and updating the indexes. If the task was stopped, will this processing be aborted mid-flow, or will the event handler method run to completion first?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a cancelation Token:

```
  CancellationTokenSource CancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
  new TaskFactory().StartNew(_indexingService.StartService,CancelationToken,
                              TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)   
.ContinueWith(TaskCancelationCallBack,TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

You cancel the token wherever in your application using:

```
 CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

You can check if your token is cancelled and throw cancel exception the task from inside:

```
if (CancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {    

    CancelationToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
}
```

You can get the task status at the ContinueWith callback:

```
private void TaskCancelationCallBack(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
{
  if (task.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.Canceled)
  {
         //Canceled
  } 
}
```

**EDIT**: In this case we used the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled` so the check in the TaskCancelationCallBack would not be necessary. It will be only fired on that premise.

Comment: The answer is almost correct. There are a few errors that need to be fixed to make it work: thew **StartNew** method expects a CancellationToken, not a CancellationTokenSource as parameter. So, you need to pass the Token property to the method. Also, it expects that you inform which TaskScheduler you want to use. You can pass either Current or the Default one. There are some other minor fixes, but you will get to them when you try to compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

@Carlos Landeras

ThrowIfCancellationRequested checks if cancelation was requested so it's redundant to embed into an if statement checking the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx

```
This method provides functionality equivalent to:
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) 
        throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you took out the call to waitOne, the task would end anyway.

To have a background task actually doing something, at some point there will need to be a loop that processes, like this

```
void ProcessItems()
{
    while(workItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ProcessItem(workItems[0]);
    }
}
```

If you want to bail out gracefully, you can do two things. In my example, I would have a flag.

```
bool m_IsRunning = true;
public void Stop()
{
    m_IsRunning = false;
}
void ProcessItems()
{
    while(workItems.Count > 0 && m_IsRunning)
    {
            ProcessItem(workItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Using Task Parallel Library, you can also pass in a `CancellationToken`.

> In the Task classes, cancellation involves cooperation between the
>   user delegate, which represents a cancelable operation and the code
>   that requested the cancellation. A successful cancellation involves
>   the requesting code calling the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method,
>   and the user delegate terminating the operation in a timely manner.
>   You can terminate the operation by using one of these options:
>
> - By simply returning from the delegate. In many scenarios this is    sufficient; however, a task instance that is "canceled" in this way
>     transitions to the RanToCompletion state, not to the Canceled state.
> - By throwing a OperationCanceledException and passing it the token on which cancellation was requested. The preferred way to do this is
>     to use the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method. A task that is
>     canceled in this way transitions to the Canceled state, which the
>     calling code can use to verify that the task responded to its
>     cancellation request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx